# Contribute basic type Hibernate 6 deprecated alternatives

Tags: java, hibernate-6.x, spring-boot-3

folks!
We are trying to migrate from 5 version Hibernate to 6 version.
We use several dialects to work with different dbs and we use same entities for it.
For postgres we don't make any additional type contribution, but for MSSQL we use pair of CharJdbcType and UUIDJavaType as a new BasicType.

``

```
    import java.util.UUID;
import org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDJavaType;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.CharJdbcType;

public class MssqlUUIDType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<UUID> {
    public static final MssqlUUIDType INSTANCE = new MssqlUUIDType();

    public SQLServerUUIDType() {
        super( CharJdbcType.INSTANCE, UUIDJavaType.INSTANCE );
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean registerUnderJavaType() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "uuid-binary";
    }

}
```

```
    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
        typeContributions.contributeType(SQLServerUUIDType.INSTANCE);
    }
```

I'm trying to contribute a new BasicType to Hibernate 6, but TypeContributions.contributeType(BasicType basicType) is deprecated and AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType is also deprecated. I found there a working method for UserType and JavaType contribution, but I don't know how to do it in the right way.
Maybe hibernate 6 already has a support of such functionality from the box.
In docs I found such solution:

```
public class MssqlUUIDType extends AbstractClassJavaType<MssqlUUIDType> {
....
}
```

but then they use such code to make it work:

```
 @JavaType(MssqlUUIDType.class)
 private UUID id;
```

But I want usage of the new type without additional annotations. Is it possible?
Could you help me to find solution for this?